# htaccess: Redirecting all paths to different structure

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wish to change all my images, css paths to the correct folder structure. I used the code below. Unfortunately nothing happened. 
I've searched and tried different solutions, but none are working for me. Any ideas?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/example/$ /singlepage/folder.sub/example/$1 [L]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change your rewrite rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^(example/.*)$ singlepage/folder.sub/$1 [L,NC]
```

And remember RewriteRule start matching without leading slash `/` from REQUEST_URI.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Unfortunately still nothing happens. The paths do not change. Could the dot (.) in the path be causing problems?

Comment: @Gavie: What URI did you try? You can try `RewriteRule ^(example/.*)$ "singlepage/folder.sub/$1" [L,NC]` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change `^/example/$` to `^/example/(.*)`, otherwise your rule matches only the path `/example/` but not `/example/somethingelse`, and you have no capture for the `$1` replacement in your rule.

Comment: Tried that. Still no luck. Could the dot (.) in the URL be causing problems?